Unable to Link Identities in AWS Congito Identity Pool with GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand
I am using Cognito Identity pool to keep track and link policies to Identities in my appilication.
I already used the command GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand to get identities and link it to my internal ID.
Now i added an OIDC provider to the Cognito IDP configuration. I can successfully obtain credentials with idToken from OIDC.
I need to Merge or Link the new Login into the already existing Identity, as i figured could be done by reading this article: https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-2-developer-authenticated-identities/.
I tried to link the identities by calling the GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand on server side and adding both the DeveloperId and the OIDC idToken on the list of Logins as it follow in various combinations:
Code:
const input = new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand({
  IdentityPoolId: 'xxxx',
  IdentityId: 'xxxx',
  Logins: {
    'developer_provider_domain': 'user-xxx',
    'oidc_id': 'idTokenJWT',
  }
});
const newId = await cognitoClient.send(input1);

Error:
InvalidParameterException: An identity pool only supports one developer provider. The logins provided have more than one developer provider.

Code:
const input = new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand({
  IdentityPoolId: 'xxxx',
  IdentityId: 'xxxx',
  Logins: {
    // 'developer_provider_domain': 'user-xxx',
    'oidc_id': 'idTokenJWT',
  }
});
const newId = await cognitoClient.send(input1);

Error:
InvalidParameterException: This identity pool does not support the specified developer provider.

Just for notice, this works but obviously doesn't link anything:
const input = new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand({
  IdentityPoolId: 'xxxx',
  IdentityId: 'xxxx',
  Logins: {
    'developer_provider_domain': 'user-xxx',
    // 'oidc_id': 'idTokenJWT',
  }
});
const newId = await cognitoClient.send(input1);

